# ObjectMapper convert to arraylist not preserving order

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json like:

```
   { "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "1"
        },
   {
            "message_id": "2"
        }
    ]}
```

When i use jackson object mapper the json returned to my collection doesnt preserve the order of messageid_1 and message id_2.
Following is my Objectmapper code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
mapper.readValue(json, Response.class);
```

Following is my Response.class

```
public class Response implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("results")
    LinkedList<Object> results;
    public LinkedList<Object> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
    public void setResults(LinkedList<Object> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }


}
```

Please help me a way to preserve the order of json objects in the array[Not the property order ,i meant objects order]

Comment: Interesting, this is not the expected behaviour can you please share more insights.

Comment: Which version of jackson are you using ?

Comment: 2.6.6 is the version

Comment: Having the same issue, can't find any configuration option for this. Only happens in nested levels.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.11.2 the order of JSON is respected